# Correct POS tags for numbers substituted with ## in spacy

Tags: python, spacy, pos-tagger

The gigaword dataset is a huge corpus used to train abstractive summarization models. It contains summaries like these:

```
spain 's colonial posts #.## billion euro loss
taiwan shares close down #.## percent
```

I want to process these summaries with *spacy* and get the correct pos tag for each token. The issue is that all numbers in the dataset were replaced with # signs which spacy does not classify as numbers (*NUM*) but as other tags.

```
>>> import spacy
>>> from spacy.tokens import Doc
>>> nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
>>> nlp.tokenizer = lambda raw: Doc(nlp.vocab, words=raw.split(' '))
>>> text = "spain 's colonial posts #.## billion euro loss"
>>> doc = nlp(text)
>>> [(token.text, token.pos_) for token in doc]
[('spain', 'PROPN'), ("'s", 'PART'), ('colonial', 'ADJ'), ('posts', 'NOUN'), ('#.##', 'PROPN'), ('billion', 'NUM'), ('euro', 'PROPN'), ('loss', 'NOUN')]
```

Is there a way to customize the POS tagger so that it classifies all tokens that only consist of #-sign and dots as numbers?

I know you replace the spacy POS tagger with your own or fine-tune it for your domain with additional data but I don't have tagged training data where all numbers are replaced with # and I would like to change the tagger as little as possible. I would prefer having a regular expression or fixed list of tokens that are always recognized as numbers.

Comment: in case you use the part to get the `#`s back: I fixed it (I had forgotten the `0`). BTW: thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about replacing `#` with a digit?

In a first version of this answer I chose the digit `9`, because it reminds me of the COBOL numeric field formats I used some 30 years ago... But then I had a look at the dataset, and realized that for proper NLP processing one should get at least a couple of things straight:

- ordinal numerals (1st, 2nd, ...)
- dates

Ordinal numerals need special handling for any choice of digit, but the digit `1` produces reasonable dates, except for the year (of course, 1111 may or may not be interpreted as a valid year, but let's play it safe). `11/11/2020` is clearly better than `99/99/9999`...

Here is the code:

```python
import re

ic = re.IGNORECASE
subs = [
    (re.compile(r'\b1(nd)\b', flags=ic), r'2\1'),  # 1nd -> 2nd
    (re.compile(r'\b1(rd)\b', flags=ic), r'3\1'),  # 1rd -> 3rd
    (re.compile(r'\b1(th)\b', flags=ic), r'4\1'),  # 1th -> 4th
    (re.compile(r'11(st)\b', flags=ic), r'21\1'),  # ...11st -> ...21st
    (re.compile(r'11(nd)\b', flags=ic), r'22\1'),  # ...11nd -> ...22nd
    (re.compile(r'11(rd)\b', flags=ic), r'23\1'),  # ...11rd -> ...23rd
    (re.compile(r'\b1111\b'), '2020')              # 1111 -> 2020
]

text = '''spain 's colonial posts #.## billion euro loss
#nd, #rd, #th, ##st, ##nd, ##RD, ##TH, ###st, ###nd, ###rd, ###th.
ID=#nd#### year=#### OK'''

text = text.replace('#', '1')
for pattern, repl in subs:
    text = re.sub(pattern, repl, text)

print(text)
# spain 's colonial posts 1.11 billion euro loss
# 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 21st, 22nd, 23RD, 11TH, 121st, 122nd, 123rd, 111th.
# ID=1nd1111 year=2020 OK
```

If the preprocessing of the corpus converts any digit into a `#` anyway, you lose no information with this transformation. Some “true” `#` would become a `1`, but this would probably be a minor problem compared to numbers not being recognized as such. Furthermore, in a visual inspection of about 500000 lines of the dataset I haven't been able to find any candidate for a “true” `#`.

N.B.: The `\b` in the above regular expressions stands for “word boundary”, i.e., the boundary between a `\w` (word) and a `\W` (non-word) character, where a word character is any alphanumeric character (further info [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)). The `\1` in the replacement stands for the first group, i.e., the first pair of parentheses (further info [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)). Using `\1` the case of all text is preserved, which would not be possible with replacement strings like `2nd`. I later found that your dataset is normalized to all lower case, but I decided to keep it generic.

If you need to get the text with `#`s back from the parts of speech, it's simply

```python
token.text.replace('0','#').replace('1','#').replace('2','#').replace('3','#').replace('4','#')
```